# Need a zip program for advanced power users

Tags: finder, software-recommendation, password, archive

I need a comprehensive solution for several thousand downloaded files which will often require passwords, including .PART files, rar files, and zip files.

I've tried UnRarX, 7zX, and Stuffit. Problems I've had:

1. Filename Consistency:

Folder names once extracted are often completely different than the original file name (usually something unrelated that makes it time consuming to figure out where the folder went, and what it is). And there are no advanced naming options to ensure filename consistency I've been able to find within any of these programs.

2. File Corruption:

I need an efficient way to check which files are corrupted and causing issues with extraction without searching through an endless list which cannot be searched or categorically organized based off extraction status.

3. Password Protection:

I need password-restricted files to prompt me when a password is needed, preferably while the program continues to extract other files still in the queue that do not require passwords (all of these programs either skip the file and don't send a notification that a password was needed, or prompt for a password and halt all extractions requested until a specific password is addressed.  Both issues = inefficiency, and are slowing me down tremendously.

Comment: Stuffit still is the best I've experienced so far. You can also try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: In contrary to the *power user*, the ***advanced** power user* also has a consistent workflow with defined constraints and doesn't have to mess around with zip apps - one will set the conditions for the compressed archives which will be sent to you...

Comment: I would look for a compression solution that takes care of these constraints built-in.  Zip may not do that.  Also, Hazel or something like it can help you automate much of this.